# assign value to data: in $.ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am working on my app and in my html a have three links evere link belong to different categories and i want to load the current category when someone has made click. But the problem reside in my function, i don´t know how to capture the selected category.

this is my code:

this are the three links in html:

```
<a id="rock" data-role="button" data-transition="slide" href="category.html">Rock</a>
    <a id="electronica" data-role="button" data-transition="slide" href="category.html">Electrónica</a>        
    <a id="pop" data-role="button" data-transition="slide" href="category.html">Pop</a>
```

this is my function, you can see at the beggining i tried something with every id but nothing happens, followed, the ajax and data should capture the name of the category.

```
var valueCat = false;

        $('#rock, #electronica').click(function () {
            if($(event.target).attr('id')=='rock'){ 
                valueCat = 'rock';
                valueCat = true; 
                return;
            }
            else if($(event.target).attr('id')=='pop'){
                valueCat = $('#pop').attr('id');  
                valueCat = true;
                return;
            }
        });


        //alert(valueCatRockArg);
        $.ajax({        
            url: 'http://.....org/api/get_category_posts',
            data:'category_name='+valueCat+'&count=5&order=desc',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data){               
                var source   = $("#category-template").html(); //Get the HTML from the template in the script tag
                var template = Handlebars.compile(source); // compilamos la plantilla
                var blogData = template(data); // en data se almacena el contenido que nos viene de wordpress
                $('#category-data').html(blogData); // mostramos el contenido
                $('#category-data').trigger('create');
                dfd.resolve(data);

            },

            error: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

i hope you understand me, i am new with apps and bad with my english.

thank you in advance!

complete function:

```
category: function(){
    function getCategory() {
        var dfd = $.Deferred();


        //alert(valueCatRockArg);
        $.ajax({        
            url: 'http://ultravoz.org/api/get_category_posts',
            data:'category_name='+valueCat+'&count=5&order=desc',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(data){               
                var source   = $("#category-template").html(); //Get the HTML from the template in the script tag
                var template = Handlebars.compile(source); // compilamos la plantilla
                var blogData = template(data); // en data se almacena el contenido que nos viene de wordpress
                $('#category-data').html(blogData); // mostramos el contenido
                $('#category-data').trigger('create');
                dfd.resolve(data);

            },

            error: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

        return dfd.promise();
    };

    getCategory().then(function(data){
        $('#all-categories').on('click','li', function(e){                
            localStorage.setItem('postData', JSON.stringify(data.posts[$(this).index()]));
        });
    });


},
```

Comment: please don't use `$(el).attr('id')` - just use `el.id` !

Comment: Try to insert `alert(1)` into `success` function, and `alert(0)` into `error` function. Which is showing?

Comment: in console shows this: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined, it means that don't find this:getCategory().then(function(data){
            $('#all-categories').on('click','li', function(e){                
                localStorage.setItem('postData', JSON.stringify(data.posts[$(this).index()]));
            });
        });

Comment: It's hard to say what is wrong. Anyway if you are new with apps I would not recommend you to use promises. It's not so easy for beginners and in most cases you can achieve what you want without it.

Comment: excuse me zum, what do you mean with promises? thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

You may try this:

```
$('#rock, #electronica, #pop').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();     //stop native link clicking
    valueCat = this.id;

    //then put your ajax call here, inside this function...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('a').click(function () {
      var cat=$(this).attr('id');
      $.ajax({        
        url: 'http://.....org/api/get_category_posts',
        data:'category_name='+cat+'&count=5&order=desc',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){               
            var source   = $("#category-template").html(); //Get the HTML from the template in the script tag
            var template = Handlebars.compile(source); // compilamos la plantilla
            var blogData = template(data); // en data se almacena el contenido que nos viene de wordpress
            $('#category-data').html(blogData); // mostramos el contenido
            $('#category-data').trigger('create');
            dfd.resolve(data);

        },

        error: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    }); 
 });
```

Your ajax function has to be called on click of the link.you are calling it outside

Comment: thank you very much both, i tried both options but nothing happens, maybe because i didn't posted the complete function, i add above